# Two dao methods in a single Spring @Transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using Spring's @Transactional with Hibernate.
I am trying to put two dao methods into a single transaction and want to rollback on a specific Exception.
Code is as follows:

Service Class method:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,value="txManager",rollbackFor=TransactionUnSuccessException.class)
public Account makeTransaction(Transaction transaction, String userName)
        throws TransactionUnSuccessException {
    Account account = null;
    account = transferDao.makeTransaction(transaction, userName);
    return account;
}
```

Dao methods:

```
@Repository
public class TransferDao extends HibernateDaoSupport {
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



public Account makeTransaction(Transaction transaction, String userName)
        throws TransactionUnSuccessException {
    HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = getHibernateTemplate();
    Account account = null;
    Session session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    //session.beginTransaction();
    updateSelfAccount(transaction, userName, session);
    account = updateAnotherAcccount(transaction, session);
    //session.getTransaction().commit();
    return account;
}

private void updateSelfAccount(Transaction transaction, String userName,
        Session session) {
    User currentUser = null;
    System.out.println("TransferDao.updateSelfAccount()" + transaction);

    Query query = session.createQuery("from User where userName=:userName");
    query.setParameter("userName", userName);
    currentUser = (User) query.list().get(0);

    currentUser.getAccount().getTransactions().add(transaction);
    currentUser.getAccount().setAvailableBalance(
            currentUser.getAccount().getAvailableBalance()
                    - transaction.getAmount());
    transaction.setTransAccount(currentUser.getAccount());
    session.save(transaction);
    session.update(currentUser.getAccount());
    session.update(currentUser);


private Account updateAnotherAcccount(Transaction transaction,
        Session session) throws TransactionUnSuccessException {

       Account account = null;
    try {
        Query query = session
                .createQuery("from Account where accNo=:accNo");
        query.setParameter("accNo", transaction.getToAcc());
        account = (Account) query.list().get(0);
        if (account.getAvailableBalance() < 5000) {
            account.setAvailableBalance(account.getAvailableBalance()
                    + transaction.getAmount());
            account.getTransactions().add(transaction);
            transaction.setTransAccount(account);
            session.save(transaction);
            session.update(account);
        } else {
            throw new TransactionUnSuccessException();
        }
    } catch (TransactionUnSuccessException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
    }

    return account;
}
}
}
```

Xml configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
   <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>
```

If any of the two method(updateSelfAccount,updateAnotherAcccount) fails the whole transaction is supposed to rollback.
But It is not able to rollback on the given Exception even i am not sure that this is all happening in a single transaction.
please correct me.

Answer (score 3):

The goal of using @Transactional annotation is that your code should not deal with the transaction itself. In your code example your use @Transactional so you should not have to do things like

```
session.beginTransaction();
```

Something else did you setup spring correctly with

```
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="datasource" ref="dataSource"
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Usually the sessionFactory is @Autowired in the dao and to get an easy access to the session you do

`sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

Last point you don't need to have a big try catch and then throwing your TransactionUnSuccessException , by default the transaction will rollback on any exception.

Comment: I have edited my code please look at It.You mean we should not deal with transaction ourself in case of @Transactional.

Comment: yes, your code should not deal with transactions if you use @Transactional

Comment: when i comment out session.beginTransaction() it says org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction.

Answer (score 0):

For starters don't use `HibernateTemplate` and/or `HibernateDaoSupport` they should be considered deprecated. Use the `SessionFactory` directly. Next NEVER use `openSession` inside a Spring managed transaction as that will open en new session, not bound to the transaction and outside of spring. Use `getCurrentSession` on the `SessionFactory` instead.

Finally **NEVER** catch and swallow exceptions, the TransactionInterceptor from spring needs the exception to decide what to do (rollback or commit)

Refactor your DAO to include all this.

```
@Repository
public class TransferDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Account makeTransaction(Transaction transaction, String userName) throws TransactionUnSuccessException {
        Account account = null;
        Session session = getSession();
        updateSelfAccount(transaction, userName, session);
        account = updateAnotherAcccount(transaction, session);
        return account;
    }
```

Another observation, judging from the amount of updates, is that you have a mapping problem. When your mappings are correct you should only have to bother with an update/save of your `User` object, everything else should be automatically persisted then.

Yet another observation, you shouldn't pass around the session, simply call the `getSession()` method (which I added to the dao). You should get the same `Session` during the whole transaction.

Final observation, your dao seems to contain business logic, which should be in the service method instead (checking the account balance for instance).